# Invoking Power Automate Desktop bot using Web API

Tags: dynamics-365, power-automate-desktop, azure-app-registration

I am trying to invoke a Power Automate Desktop bot using web api, as per the instructions provided in the below article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/developer/desktop-flow-public-apis

I created an App registration with user_impersonation privilege and I am able to get the bearer token as well. But when I hit the below API using Postman, I am getting an error stating **"The user is not a member of the organization"**.

POST https://[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.2/workflows([Workflow ID])/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.RunDesktopFlow HTTP/1.1

Can someone advise where this has to be added or what am I missing?

Regards,
Ganesh.

Comment: Could you include more details like how you generated the bearer token with what `grant_type` and `scope` by editing your question?

Comment: Sure.. grant_type - client_credentials, client_id - xxxxxxxx, client_secret - xxxxxxx, resource - htttps://org.crm4.dynamics.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error usually occurs if you missed creating **Application user** by adding **`Application ID`** of Azure AD application.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **API permission** like this:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
resource: https://orgxxxxxx.crm.dynamics.com
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to run below sample API, I got **same error** as you like below:

```
GET https://orgxxxxxxx.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/WhoAmI
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to create one **Application user** by adding **`Application ID`** of your Azure AD application.

*Go to Power Platform admin center -> Environments -> Select your organization -> Settings -> Select Application users*

[image]

Now, click on `New app user` option to create **Application user** like below:

[image]

Enter your Azure AD application **name** or **ID** in search bar and add it like this:

[image]

Now, select your organization under **`Business Unit`** and make sure to assign **System Administrator** role to create application like below:

[image]

After creating application user, I generated token again and got the **response** successfully when I used it to run sample API like this:

```
GET https://orgxxxxxxx.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/WhoAmI
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, make sure to create **Application user** by assigning proper role following the above steps.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Will try it out and update soon..

Comment: The images you have uploaded are not visible. Can you please upload them again?

Comment: Could you try accessing the same from mobile or other network?

Comment: Sure will check the same.

Comment: yes working from personal network.. thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Yes, this resolved the issue. One last thing - what is the "connectionName" parameter in the payload?