# How logic app connects with D365 using HTTP connector with Tenant ID, client ID and secret

Tags: azure-logic-apps, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to connect Microsoft Dynamics with Web API using the Logic app HTTP(s) connector.
I have the following details to connect:

- Tenant ID
- client ID
- Secret

Can someone please advise on the steps involved? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one logic app workflow and add one `HTTP` action in it with below parameters:

```http
URL: https://orgxxxxxxx.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/WhoAmI
Method: GET
```

[image]

Now, select **`Active Directory OAuth`** as Authentication type and **Save** it by entering required details:

```http
Tenant: Tenant ID
Audience: https://orgxxxxxxx.crm.dynamics.com (Your Microsoft Dynamics 365 Organization URL)
ClientID:  App ID
CredentialType: Secret
Secret: Client secret
```

[image]

When I run the logic app workflow, it executed successfully like this:

**INPUTS:**

[image]

**OUTPUTS:**

[image]

In the Body section, I got **API response** of the URL successfully like below:

[image]

Make sure to create one **Application user** by adding **`Application ID`** of your Azure AD app registration before connecting D365. You can refer this **[SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76545264/invoking-power-automate-desktop-bot-using-web-api/76586228#76586228)** by me for that.

**Reference:**
[Calling Dynamics 365 Web API from Logic App using OAuth with a Single Action by **Syed Sajid Hussain**](https://syedsajidhussain.wordpress.com/2020/05/12/calling-dynamics-365-web-api-from-logic-app-using-oauth-with-a-single-action/)