# How can I use login with Microsoft access token to acces the dynamics CRM of the user whose access token is that?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I would like to integrate whoever login into this app who as dynamics 365 account, so that they can do crud operations of accounts. I tried this code but found no luck.

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const passport = require("passport");
const OAuth2Strategy = require("passport-oauth2").Strategy;
const session = require("express-session");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Replace these values with your Dynamics 365 credentials and API endpoint
const dynamicsClientId = "<CLIENT_SECRET>";
const dynamicsClientSecret = "<CLIENT_SECRET>";
const dynamicsResource = "https://<ORG_ID>.api.crm8.dynamics.com"; // Replace with your Dynamics 365 API endpoint
const dynamicsApiVersion = "9.1"; // Adjust the API version as needed

// Set up session middleware
app.use(
  session({ secret: "your-secret-key", resave: true, saveUninitialized: true })
);

// Initialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Configure OAuth2 strategy
passport.use(
  "oauth2",
  new OAuth2Strategy(
    {
      authorizationURL:
        "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize",
      tokenURL: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token",
      clientID: dynamicsClientId,
      clientSecret: dynamicsClientSecret,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/callback", // Update this URL based on your configuration
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      // Store the user's access token in the session
      return done(null, { accessToken: accessToken });
    }
  )
);

// Serialize user to store in session
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

// Deserialize user from session
passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
  done(null, obj);
});

// Route for initiating OAuth 2.0 authentication
app.get("/auth", passport.authenticate("oauth2"));

// Callback route after successful authentication
app.get(
  "/auth/callback",
  passport.authenticate("oauth2", { failureRedirect: "/failure" }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
);

app.get("/", ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Access the user's access token from the session
    const userAccessToken = req.user.accessToken;

    // Make a request to Dynamics 365 API to get the account count (replace with your specific API endpoint)
    const response = await axios.get(
      `${dynamicsResource}/api/data/v${dynamicsApiVersion}/accounts?$count=true`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${userAccessToken}`,
        },
      }
    );

    const accountCount = response.data;

    res.send(`Total Account Count: ${accountCount}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(
      "Error:",
      error?.response?.data || error.message
    );
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
});

// Middleware to ensure user is authenticated
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect("/auth");
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

i created a multitanent application in microsoft azure and able to get the access token for the logged in user as well but no luck

I ran the above code and it seemed fine till taking the users access token but on calling the dynamics Api it throws 401 error.

Comment: What you want is _delegation_, and MS calls their implementation of it "OBO" ("On behalf of"), see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

Comment: Could you decode the token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) and check what `aud` and `scp` it has?

Comment: @Sridevi these are the audience "aud": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" and scope "scp": "User.Read",

Comment: To work with Dynamics CRM, your token `aud` should be `https://<ORG_ID>.api.crm8.dynamics.com"` (your Dynamics 365 API endpoint)

Comment: Could you try to retrieve the same via Postman once like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76545264/invoking-power-automate-desktop-bot-using-web-api/76586228#76586228?

Comment: hi @Dai, I tried "OBO" method as well but didn't find any luck

Comment: Hi @Sridevi, the "client_credential" flow worked and I am able to get data for my account. what I need is to get the data from my customers dynamics 365 account who log in into my app with their Microsoft account